# C++ assigment std::list<typename>::iterator works in main but in method it doesnt

Tags: c++, iterator

Hello :) i was wonder to make circular list based on std::list, i was serching for STL circular list but i have not found.
I have and idea to make function
who increse std::list::iterator and when iterator == list.end it assigment iterator = list.begin(). Unfortunately no match assigment operator.
i decide to use heap memory.
and assigment new iterator when old point to end of list.
its works in main function.
but as method it won't.
I have totally stuck at that, any idea about what i should think?

```
void increment_iterator(const std::list<int> & list, std::list<int>::iterator *iterator, int &val)
{
    for(int i=0;i<val;i++)
    {
        iterator->operator++();
        if(*iterator == list.end())
        {
//            *iterator = list.begin(); //here is problem
        }
    }

}

void increment_iterator(const std::list<int> & list, std::shared_ptr<std::list<int>::iterator> it, int &val)
{
    for(int i=0;i<val;i++)
    {
        it->operator++();
        if(*it==list.end())
        {
//            *it = list.begin(); //here is problem
        }
    }
}





int main() {

    std::list<int> intlist{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::list<int>::iterator *iterator = new std::list<int>::iterator;
    *iterator=intlist.begin();
    iterator++;
    *iterator=intlist.end();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target CodeWars
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CodeWars.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/tomek/Documents/C++/zadania wlasne 1/CodeWars/main.cpp: In function ‘void increment_iterator(const std::__cxx11::list<int>&, std::__cxx11::list<int>::iterator*, int&)’:
/home/tomek/Documents/C++/zadania wlasne 1/CodeWars/main.cpp:40:36: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}’ and ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<int>}’)
             *iterator = list.begin();
                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/list:63:0,
                 from /home/tomek/Documents/C++/zadania wlasne 1/CodeWars/CodeWarsCodes.h:13,
                 from /home/tomek/Documents/C++/zadania wlasne 1/CodeWars/main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:128:12: note: candidate: constexpr std::_List_iterator<int>& std::_List_iterator<int>::operator=(const std::_List_iterator<int>&)
     struct _List_iterator
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:128:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<int>}’ to ‘const std::_List_iterator<int>&’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:128:12: note: candidate: constexpr std::_List_iterator<int>& std::_List_iterator<int>::operator=(std::_List_iterator<int>&&)
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_list.h:128:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<int>}’ to ‘std::_List_iterator<int>&&’
```

this is the "correct" solution

```
void increment_iterator( std::list<int> & list, std::list<int>::iterator *iterator, int val)
{
    for(int i=0;i<val;i++)
    {
        iterator->operator++();
        if(*iterator == list.end())
        {
            *iterator = list.begin();
        }
    }

}
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: Please include the complete compiler error message in the question

Comment: why would you want to make a pointer of an iterator? that seems redundant, an iterator is a pointer already.

Comment: @StackDanny "*an iterator is a pointer already*" - more accurately, an iterator *impersonates* a pointer, but it may or may not actually *be* a pointer. This is up to the container to decide in its implementation.

Comment: @Tomek why are you `new`'ing an iterator? Don't do that. Iterators are meant to be used as value types. Allocating them dynamically is unnecessary. You can still pass them around by pointer (by reference would be better), if you want to, eg: `std::list<int>::iterator iterator = intlist.begin(); doSomething(&iterator);` But you shouldn't be invoking `operator++` the way you are. `iterator->operator++();` should be `(*iterator)++;` or `++(*iterator);` instead.

Comment: This habit of using `new` is often seen in people who come from other languages like C# or Java. There, basically everything is dynamically allocated and variables are basically all smart pointers. Neither of theses are true for C++. Avoid dynamic allocation except where it's absolutely needed, and use smart pointers when you do. Here, `std::list<int>::iterator iterator;` is better than `std::list<int>::iterator *iterator = new std::list<int>::iterator;` But `auto iterator = intlist.begin();` would be best.

Answer (score 2):

With `const std::list<int> & list` you have a `const` list so `list.begin()` calls the `const` overload which returns `std::list::const_iterator` this is then not convertible to `std::list::iterator`.

You either need to remove const from your list reference or use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main has undefined behaviour.

```
iterator++;
*iterator=intlist.end();
```

You increment the *pointer* to the iterator, which does not point into an array of iterators, and then dereference it.

Besides that, you leak the iterator object.

Besides that, there is no point using dynamic allocation here, it just makes things harder to understand.

If you want a function that modifies an iterator, pass it by reference, or change it to a pure function that **returns** the required iterator value.

```
void cyclic_advance(std::list<int> & list, std::list<int>::iterator & it, std::size_t distance)
{
    distance %= list.size();
    size_t remaining = std::distance(it, list.end());
    if (distance >= remaining) { 
        std::advance(list.begin(), distance - remaining);
    } else { 
        std::advance(it, distance); 
    }
}

std::list<int>::iterator cyclic_next(std::list<int> & list, std::list<int>::iterator it, std::size_t distance)
{
    distance %= list.size();
    size_t remaining = std::distance(it, list.end());
    if (distance >= remaining) { 
        return std::next(list.begin(), distance - remaining);
    }
    return std::next(it, distance);
}
```